# Should we close this old off-topic question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

I was looking for some information for unzipping a file with C++ and came across [Lightweight library for reading ZIP files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354553/lightweight-library-for-reading-zip-files). The question is in good standing and has both positive answers and an accepted answer. Is this a post that fell under the radar or is the policy to close questions asking for libraries newer than when the question was asked?

If it was an on-topic question when posted, but is now considered off-topic, what should we do anything about it or leave it alone? Also do we keep a record of when a topic becomes off-topic?

Comment: Yes.​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: It is nice that now there is a (beta) site where such questions **are** on topic:  [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @PM77-1 should we have a "This question belongs to another SE page (software recommendations) " close flag then? If we would, that site will get out of beta in about ~3 days.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I believe that if you want to request that it be moved and it is not a standard option then you should flag it as other and explain why it should be moved and a moderator should be able to move it.

Comment: @NathanOliver When I flagged an older question to be moved to a different SE page it was declined with this message: "declined - posts older than 60 days cannot be migrated ". So you may not want to do this if the question is old.

Comment: @ChristianWilkie I did not know that.  Thanks for the information.

Comment: How was it on-topic when asked?

Comment: 10 downvotes now ... should we really be bombarding old questions with downvotes just because they don't fit today's guidelines? Seems like a good way to alienate those that have been here the longest.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are lots of questions that meet the criteria for closure that aren't closed.  Some just didn't get enough attention to attract close votes, some didn't merit closure at the time they were asked but now do, etc.

At the end of the day, it's all irrelevant.  If you see a question that merits closure, vote to close it.  Whether it was on topic when asked, or if it was simply missed, doesn't change how you should treat it.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that closure isn't deletion, so the question (and its answers) will still be visible.  It just won't allow any new answers.

Comment: @ryanyuyu True, but this one will probably get deleted. Questions like it are deleted routinely and closing it is a prerequisite.

Comment: I don't like the idea of deleting useful answers like this though.

Comment: @JonasCz A handful of spam links isn't exactly particularly useful content.

Comment: @JonasCz about 1/4 of a second of search-engineing will outdo those answers.

Comment: I would not think of them as "spam links". I found exactly the library I needed through such an answer (not this one though). In this case, they're really not all that useful, so yes, it's probably okay to delete them IMO.

Comment: @Radiodef: Questions with *accepted* answers are never automatically deleted, no matter how long they have been closed. They can be manually deleted with enough votes, but that rarely happens.

Comment: @GregHewgill Also true. I meant to refer to deletion by 15k users, though in retrospect I guess it wasn't clear.

Comment: @Radiodef s/15/10/

Comment: @JonasCz Well a `1/4 of a second of search-engineing` did help me, it helped me find the Q/A which was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

I think that by '11 the rules were more set in stone than for example '09, or even mid '10. The vintage of this question means it should be eligible for closure as you indicate.

Further, as it has low views (3 per day on average), low votes (none at the moment), and no high voted answers I would say the content in the post is not something of value which needs to be protected.

Closure was, in my opinion, the correct avenue and even deletion of this post wouldn't really be of any significance as there isn't any valuable content there to protect - it is mostly links.