# Is it worth any value to close a 5 year old question with no activity in over a year?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, on-hold

I got a little notification that one of [my questions that I asked 5 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147741/using-a-bsd-licensed-library-in-a-gpl-application) was "put on hold" (aka closed) because it was off topic.

The question hadn't seen any activity in over a year, so it's not like closing the question is going to affect anything, except that it has one rather important side effect: it's a slap in the face to me.

Are there really just people going around looking for old dead questions to close just to annoy long time contributors?  I seriously question the value of this activity.  Certainly over on P.SE we've lost a bunch of high value contributors over needling them like this (I'm thinking of Rachel and Pierre 303), and I completely understand why they'd feel this way.

Comment: Your question as well as the other old posts about legal issues served as a broken window: other users ask legal questions on SO and then are annoyed that those are closed, pointing to posts like yours ("why is my question being closed when this five year old one is still open?"). You lose exactly nothing when your question is closed, so why do you even care about it?

Comment: I don't *"[go] around looking for old dead questions to close"*, but if I'm researching an issue and come across an off-topic post, I mark it as such.

Comment: For what it's worth, Law.SE is starting public beta soon and these questions will be quite on topic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a drive that is marking all legal request/ licensing questions as off topic.  See [Should we add an off-topic close reason to specifically address legal requests?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295593/should-we-add-an-off-topic-close-reason-to-specifically-address-legal-requests?cb=1).  I know I did this once when I was googling and I found a question that looked off topic to me.  I did a post [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294217/should-we-close-this-old-off-topic-question) to ask the community what to to and the consensus was that even if it is old if it is off topic it should be marked as such.

Answer (score 7):

Since you specifically mentioned Programmers, we are actually [doing just that](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7285/22815) right now.

The primary reason is that over time, what the community decides is on-topic may change. Perhaps certain types of questions prove to be problematic and are categorically made off-topic and old questions closed, possibly deleted. Maybe certain questions provide little value. Whatever the reason, the community decides they do not belong.

Many Stack Exchange sites do this every once in a while. I do not believe it is anything personal against you or your question. Both Stack Overflow and Programmers appear to have clamped down on licensing and copyright questions over the years because they can constitute legal advice (never a good idea to give or take legal advice on the interwebs) or are too highly specific to be of any lasting value.

Answer (score 2):

There's a [drive to close licencing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295117/this-tag-should-not-be-legal/295218#295218) questions. If you don't agree with that you could downvote it and also (as suggested by deduplicator) post a comprehensive and convincing answer explaining why you disagree so your downvote is not lost in the sea of upvotes.

That question is driving the closure of all old licencing questions as they enourage other similar off topic questions.

It's the [broken windows theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory).

Comment: Actually, a single downvote would be rightly ignored (there is nearly always someone dissenting, maybe just for the heck of it. And anyway, few would ever even notice). He also needs to post a comprehensive and convincing argument why either tag-cleanup is generally evil, how those questions are actually on-topic and nobody else can read, or that SO should allow law questions.

Comment: That's just ridiculous. The argument **for** cleansing the licensing question was not posted as "a comprehensive and convincing argument" at all. All the reasoning is numbers game. Why would one place such a burden on someone who disagree to such reasoning. If it's a democracy or majority rule, why not be honest.

Comment: @tinlyx It may be, I'm just trying to explain the way it is here, not justify it. If you think it is ridiculous, create a question explaning your point of view. If it gets upvoted enough the policy will likely change.

Comment: @RobertLongson I don't mean the drive or the way it is, or your answer is ridiculous. I meant the comment that requires others to use comprehensive reasoning against majority rule. I should probably use more qualification in my comments. No offense.

Comment: Also, looking at the speed questions that  go against the crowd gets down-voted and closed here, you think anyone older than 1k+ rep would bother to try get upvotes on policy change? :)